# Permit specific user to sudo specific command without enter password

Tags: sudo

For developing a game server I want to `git push` my current stable to a private VPS. Inside the git-hook `receive` the following should happen

```
sudo systemctl stop myserver
dotnet publish --configuration release
sudo systemctl start myserver
```

Inside the myserver.service the compiled binary is run as the user that has access to the git-repository.

My idea now was to replace the first and last line by scripts owned by root and readable by everyone so the git-hook `receive` turns into

```
sudo stop-server.sh 
dotnet publish --configuration release
sudo start-server.sh
```

As a final step I want to allow the user privileges to sudo-invoke both scripts but nothing else. In addition the scripts executed without having sudo ask for the users password since there is no interaction possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the following to `/etc/sudoers` (or create a new file inside `/etc/sudoers.d/`):

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

That would make running `sudo /path/to/script` as the `<username>` user passwordless. Note that it is insecure if the contents of the script can be modified by a malicious user, and you are better off trying to avoid needing root privileges altogether.